# Problem with Session Cookie

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, session-cookies

I'm using Google App Engine and a servlet-based application.

I know that the container specification says that when called response.getSession() by a servlet the whole session management process starts in the background and the response should contain a sessionid cookie. The problem is that I'm not getting the that cookie and the problem comes from the server because I've tried sending a "hand-made" cookie and that one is received correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like sessions are disabled by default so you have to enable the feature yourself by adding `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>` to the `appengine-web.xml` file.